# One CSS element rendered...others are not

Tags: css

I'm trying to tweak code that rendered by Glimmer which probably marks my CSS mastery kinda low....

I have HTML like:

```
<ul id="main_navigation">
  <li id="trigger0"><a /Topics">Webinar Topics</a>
  <ul  class="subNavMenuItems" id="subNav0">
    <li><a href="/Topics/15">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Topics/25">Computer Skills</a></li>[and so on]
```

In my css i have:

```
#main_navigation ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    font-size:13px;
    font: bold;
    font-variant: small-caps;

}
```

the width rule *is* observed - but none of the others are. The file containing these rules are the last file imported so these rules should override any others (though 'main_navigation' is the only matching element _anyway so cascading stuff shouldn't matter.

Comment: The missing quote in the a tag was my cut 'n paste. Adding li _will produce the correct result on the 2nd tier list items but doesn't effect the top level. (trigger0) Should be a matter of adding a class identifier to those top level elements but I'm not hitting the correct syntax. I'm using firebug and am landing inside the elements as expected. Again....now stuff works a the 2nd level of ULs but not the top.

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#main_navigation li {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Initial test made me think this cracked the nut but there's still a bit to work out (please comment above)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact solution for you, but I'm certain that things will become easy if you use firefox and install firebug.  Firebug has a mode that shows all of the style sheet info that could affect an element.  It also shows how different rules interact while allowing you to try changing things without reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Also, missing a double quote in `<a /Topics">` and the href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`#main_navigation ul` should match, from the HTML code shown, your ul with the ID subNav0.  Do you have any CSS styling `.subNavMenuItems` or `#subNav0`, or perhaps `ul li ul`, which would also get to the same thing as `#main_navigation ul`? If you do have any such CSS, it is potentially mucking with the CSS shown.  To be absolutely specific, you could style `ul#main_navigation li#trigger0 ul#subNav0`.

Ben has a good suggestion with trying the [Firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) for Firefox.

This HTML is invalid:  `<a /Topics">Webinar Topics</a>`.  You want `<a href="/Topics">Webinar Topics</a>` most likely.

Answer (score 0):

What element are you trying to style?

```
#main_navigation ul {
/* css here */
}
```

Surely styles a `ul` that's a direct descendant of `#main_navigation`, whereas you're trying to style (I *think*) either the outer-menu which *is* `#main_navigation` or the inner `ul` which is `#main_navigation li ul` ...unless I'm reading this badly?